# I want to get a distance and percentage from the ultrasonic sensor but I only manage get the distance

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, python-unicode

I am trying to get the percentage. Based on the code below, what else should I do?

```
 - ********#Libraries  
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  #Import GPIO library
   import time  #Import time library
    
      GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                      #GPIO Mode (BOARD / BCM)  
   
    
  GPIO_TRIGGER = 18  
   GPIO_ECHO = 24                        #set GPIO Pins  
     
     
   #set GPIO direction (IN / OUT)  
   GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)  
   GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)  
    
   def distance():  
        
       GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)   # set Trigger to HIGH 
      
       time.sleep(0.00001)  
       GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)  # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    
       StartTime = time.time()  
       StopTime = time.time()  
    
         
       while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:  # save StartTime
           StartTime = time.time()  
    
         
       while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:  # save time of arrival
           StopTime = time.time()  
    
        
       TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime  # time difference between start and arrival
        # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)  
       # and divide by 2, because there and back  
       distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2  
    
       return distance  
   def percentage(temp) :  
       percentage = round(((binheight - temp)/binheight)*100, 2)   
       return percentage  
    
   if __name__ == '__main__':  
       try:  
           while True:  
               dist = distance()  
               percent = percentage(dist)  
               print ("Measured Distance = %.1f cm" % dist)  
               print ("Percentage", percent, "%")  
               time.sleep(1)  
    
            
       except KeyboardInterrupt:   # Reset by pressing CTRL + C
           print("Measurement stopped by User")  
           GPIO.cleanup()********
```

Comment: Where is defined `binheight`?

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking this, where should i put the define binheight? Is it def percentage(temp, binheight):

Comment: Yes, in `def percentage(temp, binheight)` (and adjust all calls to that function).

Comment: There is error at dist = distance( ) and if i try to adjust all call to that function it shows a new error. I just don’t know what else should i do. Can you help me to adjust this coding? I really aprreciate this if you can help me. Thank you so much

Comment: "*I just don’t know what else should i do.*" Switch to *Python-3*. If you need further help here: please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In particular, include error traceback…